# How would I play a .wav file with a Mathematica program?

Tags: audio, wolfram-mathematica, wav

I would like to know an easy way to implement a function `playWav[filename_String]` that plays a .wav file (as a side effect).

Comment: When I typed  data =Import["file.wav"], Mathematica 8 automatically showed a little gui window with a button to click on to play the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
playSound[filename_String] := EmitSound @ Import[filename, "WAV"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the "wav" to "Sound" allows it to play without GUI

```
playSound[filename_String] := EmitSound @ Import[filename, "Sound"]
```